# Rewrite URLs for LeadPages due to subdirectory installation

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, directory

I am using LeadPages on a WordPress site (with the LeadPages Connector plugin), and need help improving its URLs.

My WP installation has its own directory (wp/) in the docroot of the server (per https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), so I have:

`site.com/about-me/` <-- site pages

`site.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/photo.jpg` <-- uploaded files

LeadPages seems to be unable to accommodate this configuration. When I create a landing page in the LeadPages plugin, it includes the WP directory `wp/`, so the URL is `site.com/wp/landing-page/`.

Oddly, this LeadPages URL actually works, and the `wp/` persists after the request, whereas if I manually append 'wp/' after the domain on any normal WP page, WordPress redirects/rewrites(?) to remove it, before showing the page.

**MY QUESTION** -- How can I remove `wp/` from my LeadPages URL, so visitors can request `site.com/landing-page/` -- AND that URL persists in the browser address-bar (without the `wp/`)?

I've tried many variations of htaccess rewrites and redirects, wp's add_rewrite_rule(), and the Quick Redirects plugin. No luck yet.

For example, these failed:

in htaccess

```
RewriteRule  ^landing-page/$  wp/landing-page/
```

in functions.php

```
function my_rewrites() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^landing-page/?', 'wp/landing-page/', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrites' );
```

By the way, this site is on GoDaddy WordPress managed hosting. Maybe there's confusing caching or other restrictions coming from there?

Thanks in advance.